# How to call a recursive Async function in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'd like to check if a particular bool function returns true. If so, run a random number generator and try to check the bool function again. And again and again, until the result is false. Then stop the recursion and end the function.

This is an idea of what i want to do, but im not quite sure how to recall the random number again and again until hasDataBeenSeen() returns false. Please help!

```
    async hasDataBeenSeen(key) {
       var obj = userData[];  //pre-populated string array

       if (obj.indexOf(key) > -1) {
         //In the array!
         return true
       } 
       else {
         //Not in the array
         return false
       }
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

 async executeFunction() {  
    const dbIndex = this.getUniqueRandomNumber(this.state.ArrayLength); //gets a random +ve integer

    //Check if this string in the array has been seen (return true or false)
    if(!await this.hasDataBeenSeen(this.state.Data[dbIndex].Key))  ///this.state.Data[] is an array. ALSO if the string is not in the array (i.e. false) then we have what we need and finish the function 
    {
        if(dbIndex != null){
              this.setState({ finalString: this.state.Data[dbIndex].Key });   //Set the string locally and finish function
        }     
    } 
    else
    {
       //call the random number function again ???
        this.getUniqueRandomNumber(this.state.ArrayLength)
    }  
  }
```

Comment: why is `hasDataBeenSeen` asynchronous?

Comment: because i've simplified how i get the userData[]. It actually calls an await function to get data from DynamoDB. Didn't think its relevant to the logic i need

Comment: instead of `this.getUniqueRandomNumber(this.state.ArrayLength)` in the `else` of `executeFunction` have you tried just calling `executeFunction` (itself) again?

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to understand how your functions affect each other, but this is probably what you want

```
waitForSuccess = async () => {
  let success = false
  let dbIndex
  do {
    dbIndex = this.getUniqueRandomNumber(this.state.ArrayLength)
    success = !(await this.hasDataBeenSeen(this.state.Data[dbIndex].Key))
  } while (!success)
  return dbIndex
}

// use it somewhere

const dbIndex = await this.waitForSuccess()
this.setState({ finalString: this.state.Data[dbIndex].Key })
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a while statement?

```js
while (await hasDataBeenSeen(key)) {
  functionToExecute();
  //wait 5 ms to try again for example
}
```

Comment: Perhaps. How do i ensure it'll call my random number generator function if hasDataBeenSeen() is true?

Comment: Put it inside the while code block, it will execute while true

Comment: I uṕdated the answer

Comment: So key will change everytime. Because somewhere i need to call this.getUniqueRandomNumber(this.state.ArrayLength) to generate a new number to get a new key EACH time the while loop is called